# Computer freezes such that ctrl-alt-f3 doesn't work; what are the alternatives for recovery?

Tags: linux, tty

It seems most questions I find is about ctrl-alt-f3 not working at all. However, that's not the case for me, it generally works. However, sometimes when playing video games, the view freezes (albeit I can still move the mouse), and I can't switch out to tty, it just ignores my presses until I hard reboot. What gives? What alternatives do I have to get to the shell? I'm using fedora38, KDE with xserver and i3wm replacement.